# Creating large pdf file with Adobe Air

Tags: actionscript-3, air, alivepdf

I'm trying to create a pdf file using alivepdf lib with about 4000 pages and each page contains an image added by the alivepdf method addImage(). the problem is that the data takes a lot of memory because alivepdf creates the whole file in the memory before saving it to desk. so i am asking if there is a away i can open the file with each entry and add page then close it and free memory before adding the next page.
thanks

Comment: Maybe making multiple smaller PDFs and then use some tool (even as a NativeProcess) to combine them all into one from disk?

Comment: wont't it overload memory when combining all the pdf files again?

Comment: I meant first use your app to make many small PDFs (eg: 400 pages) save and do next 400 as new PDF etc. When ready then use an external tool like **[PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/)** to process the files you saved to disk. It works from command prompt but you can tell AIR to run as NativeProcess. It **[accepts instructions](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/)** to combine saved files and output as a new one. Nothing is loaded into Flash. Flash can start the process but the merging will happen outside your app. Just wait for a big file to magically appear...

Comment: I do not know how to thank you for your help,
can you please post it as an answer so i can vote it

Comment: Are you okay with starting a NativeProcess or you need a hint for that? If yes let me know so I add that part later on (I have to leave this computer soon)...

Comment: thanks a lot, yeah no problem with starting NativeProcess , i really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you first use your app make many much smaller PDFs (for example each one is 400 pages, then next 400 as a new PDF, so on until all 4000 pages are done in 10 PDFs).

When those are ready, use an external tool like **[PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/)** to process those files you saved to disk. It works from command prompt but you can tell AIR to run it as a `NativeProcess`. It accepts **[instructions](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/)** to combine those saved files and output them as a new big one.

Don't worry about memory, nothing is loaded into Flash. Flash itself can start the process but the merging will happen outside your app. Just wait for a big file to magically appear.

Comment: Thanks, that is the best way to do it